# Can we modify close buttons to alert view UILocalnotification dialog

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I have a task to develop the application with `UILocalnotification` and modify button of alert dialog box.

How can we modify close button with user custom name to `UILocalnotification` `alertview` dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify only view button title, pressing which will open your app.